# Apache Reverse Proxy Authorization Header

Tags: apache, rest, api, proxy

I want to pass my authorization header to back end server and it is not working for days.

AngularJS ----> Reverse Proxy -------> REST API IN Tomcat (basic authentication) Now reverse proxy strips the header "Authorization" and API fails and we are not able to fix that.

Please help